# put last x commits in stash to do those changes on another branch

Tags: git

Question is quite clear I think
i accidentally did 3 commits to master (no push). I would now like to propagate these changes to a new branch.

These are my commits

```
commit f00cf47c7fe701055965a3ab83013714482a8d7c (HEAD -> master)
Author: sgerrits <steven.ger@cp.com>
Date:   Wed Sep 23 14:09:53 2020 +0200

    #33 fix nw match (duplicate_key error)

commit 6d5daf678ee51a42e5a90a78afb5447652e877cb
Author: sgerrits <steven.ger@cp.com>
Date:   Wed Sep 23 11:10:25 2020 +0200

    #33 change dirty to synced

commit d10addb67c3efd6df541a9f993661a5bf1665034
Author: sgerrits <steven.ger@cp.com>
Date:   Tue Sep 22 17:51:29 2020 +0200

    #33 Add dirty field
```

Comment: You don't need to stash them, just create a new branch for master then reset master back behind them.

Comment: Just cherry-pick the commits to your other branch and reset master back to master~3.

Comment: @choroba I did cherry-pick the commits succesfully. How do I reset the master?

Comment: `git checkout master ; git reset master~3`. Check that there are no other changes, and discard them. Or you can do `git reset --hard master~3` if you're sure there are no other changes.

Answer (score 1):

The commits exist on the local master branch, so there's no need to stash anything.

Just cherry-pick the commits from master to your other branch, and then reset master back:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard master~3
```

If you want to be sure you aren't losing any changes, don't do a hard reset and check the changes before discarding them.